# Where should a well-behaved daemon store auxiliary files?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, backup, daemon

I have a daemon that backs up some system files before it does anything else and restores them afterwards. What is the right place to put these backups? I'm thinking somewhere in /var or /var/opt, since I don't want to pollute /etc with a bunch of backup files that aren't really doing anything.

If it matters, I'm specifically looking at Ubuntu 10.04+.

Comment: sounds like /var/cache/daemon_name would work.

Answer (score 0):

If they are not to be maintained after a reboot or between invocations of the program why not use /tmp

This directory contains mostly files that are required temporarily. Many programs use this to create lock files and for temporary storage of data.

Comment: They are maintained after boot in case of a daemon/system crash. So /tmp is out.